# Getting the correct height of an element is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a mobile menu that I'm having some issues with. When clicking on an item with sub-items I want to get the entire height of that sub menu and set the height of it to that value (after I set the value to 0 for when nothing is clicked yet).

My current code:

HTML structure:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My JS:

```
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('header nav ul li.menu-item-has-children');

listItems.forEach(function (el, i) {
    let subNav;
    var clicked = false;
    subNav = el.querySelector('.sub-menu');
    subNav.setAttribute('data-height', subNav.getBoundingClientRect().height);
    console.log(subNav.getAttribute('data-height'));
    subNav.style.height = 0;

    el.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (!clicked) {
            e.preventDefault();
            el.classList.toggle('active');

            if (el.classList.contains('active')) {
                subNav.style.height = subNav.getAttribute('data-height') + 'px';

            } else {
                subNav.style.height = 0;
            }
        }
        clicked = !clicked;
    });
});
```

The strange thing is when I log the height values of `subnav` I get `48` and `24` (I have two menu items with sub menus) but if I inspect the elements I see their actual heights are `122` and `61`. How can that be?

What is the correct way to get the height of `sub-menu`? I currently try: `subNav.getBoundingClientRect().height`

I've also tried: `subNav.offsetHeight` and `subNav.clientHeight` but all give me the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code should get the height of the element:

```
let subNavStyles = getComputedStyle(subNav);
let subNavHeight = subNavStyles.getPropertyValue('height');

subNav.setAttribute('data-height', subNavHeight);
```